# pleskbackup - FTPS - certificate verification

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, centos7, ftps, plesk

I have a question. I have to backup webserver through FTPS and I want to backup that server in a secure way, so I want to verify server's certificate. At the begining, pleskbackup was throwing this:

> Using the default of SSL_verify_mode of SSL_VERIFY_NONE for client
>   is deprecated! Please set SSL_verify_mode to SSL_VERIFY_PEER
>   together with SSL_ca_file|SSL_ca_path for verification.
>   If you really don't want to verify the certificate and keep the
>   connection open to Man-In-The-Middle attacks please set
>   SSL_verify_mode explicitly to SSL_VERIFY_NONE in your application.

So I have changed:


SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE

to:

SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_PEER

(in /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/IO/Socket/SSL.pm)

It's ok now, but where I can put certificate of the FTPS server and how can I force pleskbackup to verify that certificate?

I have:

> CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708
>
> perl-5.16.3-292.el7.x86_64
>
> perl-IO-Socket-SSL-1.94-6.el7.noarch

Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a workaround. I'm making backup of the webserver to the file and I'm transfering that file via lftp (I'm forcing lftp to SSL connection). I made a config file in "~/.lftp/rc":

```
set ftp:ssl-force true
set ftp:ssl-protect-data true
set ftp:ssl-protect-list true
set ssl:verify-certificate true
set ssl:ca-file "certificate.crt"
```